# Google Maps API v3 and jQuery - animate map div resize while keeping map center

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a div where I placed a Google Map (API v3). I have managed to resize it using the .animate jQuery function, and I have managed to update the map center when the div is finished resizing so as to keep the center in the same position. However, I have not figured out any way to make the center stay the same while the div resize animation is showing.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks,
FS

Comment: I would look at the `progress` property of animate (so long you are using jquery 1.8+).

Answer (score 0):

Can you call

```
map.setCenter()
```

and call it at each interval of the animate?

If you call it inside the jQuery step function, I would imagine it would work.